# Record last time the client was connected

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have implemented a timer app (Windows Form) which records start & end of a task. Some times we lose connection between my app & ASP.Net app at server side. Due to this it does not record the end time. To fix this issue I implemented a logic which hits to server every 2 seconds and adds and entry in the database about that user & current time (bad practice). This makes SQL server exe consume CPU more than 95%.

I want to record the last time before my client app got disconnected. Is there any other technology/technique/approach to solve this problem?

Comment: What kind of connection are you establishing between your apps? What data exchange is happening between your apps?  In order to help you, I need a little more info

Comment: SQLClient open connection, update the record and close connection from client app to server database directly.